# Call activity from Application

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-digits, android-application-class

I am trying to use **Digits** from **Twitter**.
The **AuthCallBack** is not fired when used from activity and the recent [document](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/digits.html#configure-the-button-in-an-activity) saying to use the AuthCallBack from the **Application** class.

Now I have the **AuthCallBack** working correctly and onSuccess I need to call a method from my MainActivity. How do I achieve it from the Application class. Kindly help. I have given the code below.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private AuthCallback authCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {

                //call myFunction() from MainActivity here

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {

            }
        };
    }

    public AuthCallback getAuthCallback(){
        return authCallback;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use BroadcastManager to archive the same. 
Below is sample code you can use

From Application:

```
    @Override
    public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.FILTER_LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mInstance).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Activity Class :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Constants.FILTER_LOGIN_SUCCESS));
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            navigateToAnotherActivty();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Drup, it works fine now, the only issue being the onReceive is called twice. How do I fix this ? Please suggest.

Comment: It should be only ones. Did you register your broadcast with any other intent filter.?

Answer (score 4):

Using interface you can achieve this

Write an interface something like this

```
public interface onSuccessListner {
    void onSuccess(DigitsSession session,String phoneNumber);
}
```

Implement this interface in your Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements onSuccessListner{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DigitsSession session,String phoneNumber) {
        //write your method calling or operations here
        }
}
```

In your application class implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to check main activity is created or not,If main activity created apply context of main activity to the listner

In on create inside your callback method call the success method of the MainActivity

```
public class MyApplctn extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    onSuccessListner onSuccessListner;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {

                //call myFunction() from MainActivity here
                if(onSuccessListner!=null){
                    onSuccessListner.onSuccess(session,phoneNumber);
                 }
           }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            onSuccessListner= (com.mmadapps.myapplication.onSuccessListner) activity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you